# Navigation Bar not showing Title when navigating between navigation controllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

**I am trying to build an app with chat options integrated. My conversations view controller(where all the chats of one person are displayed in a tableView with multiple cells) is embedded in a navigation controller as well as the single chat view controller(where you are chatting with only one person).**

**To go from the conversations view controller to the single chat view controller I am implementing this code:**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let _vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
        _vc.title = "John Smith"
        _vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(_vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**However, the _vc.title is not showing on the navigation bar. How could I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

```
_vc.navigationItem.title = "John Smith"
```

Set title using navigation item.

Comment: This will not work because OP is present view controller without navigation controller

Comment: Embed the presented controller in navigation controller.

Comment: Ohh I thought it’s VC. As he given wrong name conversion so

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of UINavigationController first:

```
 UINavigationController *navController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Viewe"];
ViewController2 *vc = (ViewController2 *) [navController topViewController];

navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

vc.title = @"hello";
```

and present that navController instance.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a VC that you are presenting first of all and incase you are considering of adding a VC then it goes something like this.

#### In Swift:

---

```
 let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 guard let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecViewController") as? SecViewController else { return }
 let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
 navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
 present(navController, animated: true)
```

And in the `viewDidLoad` of SecViewController give
`title = "John Smith"`. This will help you add title.